# Access Magento Admin panel using ip address and user name

Tags: php, magento, authentication, admin

Hi I have setup a magento store on a server. but currently we dont have a domain name.i have changed the core config data table values (web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url) like this:
http://{server ip address}/~User name

I can view the site front end, but i cannot log into admin panel like this.
http://{server ip address}/~User name/admin

but i cannot log.  Some one can please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your admin path from `local.xml` open your `local.xml` file from

```
app>etc>local.xml
```

at the end you can see like

[image]

`<<frontName>`if it set is like admin then admin URL of your site like

yoursite.com/admin

Comment: :but currently we don't have a domain name. i was trying to access using server ip address as i mentioned above. http://{server ip address}/~User name/admin

Comment: when you access http://{server ip address}/~User name/admin URL have you got 404 page or something like that?

Comment: have you check your admin path in local.xml?

Comment: it says:  <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

Comment: its working.i didnt change the local file. i just typed http://{server ip address}/index.php/admin on browser. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try:

`http://{server ip address}/~username/index.php/admin`

Comment: This worked, but it redirects to the domain name upon login in.